# String? - which means the question mark when initializing the variable in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

in the code example i found something like this:

```
String? selectedNotificationPayload;
```

which means the question mark next to the type of the String variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means the type is `NullableString`. This works for Flutter 2 and above due to null-safety in dart. It basically means the value stored can be a `null`.

So, `String? foo;` allows `null` but `String bar;` does not allow `null`.

https://dart.dev/codelabs/dart-cheatsheet
https://dart.dev/null-safety